# Public member 'Contains' on type 'String()' not found

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have 3 string arrays but the third, 'a3', throws:

> Public member 'Contains' on type 'String()' not found.

at `a3.Contains("a")`

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim a1 As String() = {"a", "b", "c"}
    Dim a3 = {"a", "b", "c"}

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim a2 = {"a", "b", "c"}
        a1.Contains("a")
        a2.Contains("a")
        a3.Contains("a")
    End Sub
End Class
```

All 3 are of type `System.String[]`.

Comment: Type inference works differently when dealing with Fields and Local Variables. In `Dim a3 = {"a", "b", "c"}`, `a3` is a Instance Field, it's treated as an `Object()` (what else you'll put inside this collection later is undefined). In  `Dim a2 = {"a", "b", "c"}`, `a2` is a local variable, with `Option Infer On`, this is interpreted based on the values that you assign *right now*: all strings, so `a2` is of type `String()`. With `Option Strict On`, you'd know about this as soon as you write it.

Comment: @Jimi I figured it out when I decompiled the application. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with [Local Type Inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/local-type-inference).

> The Visual Basic compiler uses type inference to determine the data
>   types of **local** variables declared without an As clause.

The variable-type is only inferred on local variables. Because `a3` is a class-level variable, it is of type `Object` which has no `Contains`-method.

Whenever possible, you should set `Option Strict On` and declare all variables with the correct type.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out when I decompiled the application.

Comment: Should this be considered a bug? If a3 is declared as Object and the get type() method return System.String[].

Comment: No, this isn't a bug. Have a look at the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype

Comment: It's not a bug. Turn `Option Strict On`, as suggested, and then you won't be able to do things like allow fields or methods to be implicitly typed as `Object`. You also ought to specify an access level for all fields, which will generally be `Private`.